# JQuery Mobile Menu static on page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to fix the top menu on page change.
Example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    //page 1 contents
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    //page 2 contents
</div>
```

and my top menu

```
<div id="top-menu">
</div>
```

Is there any way to not make the menù code reappear on each page? 
I want my menu div to be collective for all pages.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the concept of "pages" does not allow for static content to be shared among them.

But I see at least two solutions:

- use only one page containing your menu, and many hidden `div` to encapsulate your content (like `<div data-role="content" id="page1" class="hidden">`). Using your menu navigation, you just have to show/hide the content you need
- use some JavaScript trickery:

  ```
  $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "[id^=page]", function(event)
  {
      // "move" the menu to the content of the current page
      // (you have to add IDs to each page like 'page1content')
      $("#top-menu").prependTo("#" + this.id + "content");
  });
  ```

Comment: Great! I used first solution and it works fine. Thanks